# How can I import SciPy correctly into PyDev?

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, scipy, pydev

I cannot compile the program with the error from line 4 with the import of the stats package from SciPy. I am currently using PyDev on Eclipse 2019 and programming in PYthon 2.7.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
from . import stats as csestats
from scipy.stats import linregress, ttest_ind
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users...viz.py", line 4, in 
    from . import stats as csestats
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Comment: as far as I'm aware there is no library called `.`

Comment: Sorry that was a mistype. It should be from line 4. Line 3 works perfectly.

Comment: the code only works for me if I comment out line 3

Comment: I was able to get the program to run even with these errors if I changed the program that called this class to change to plt.show(). PyDev still flags the 4th line as an error, but compiles fine.